# How to display child menu item under their parent item in php?

Tags: php

I need to display all child menu items under their corresponding parent items in php.
I have created mysql query but i am unable to get all child items under their parent items.Here is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {

    echo'<li><a href="' . $url . $menu[$i]['id'] . '" title="' . $menu[$i]["menu_name"] . '">' . $menu[$i]["menu_name"] . '</a>';
    if ($menu[$i]['parent_id'] != "0" && $menu[$i]['parent_id'] != null) {
        echo'<ul>';
        echo'<li><a href="#" title="' . $menu[$i]["submenu_name"] . '">' . $menu[$i]["submenu_name"] . '</a></li></ul></li>';
    }
}

MySQL Query: SELECT m.id, m.menu_name, sm.parent_id,sm.submenu_name,sm.id
    FROM menu AS m
    LEFT JOIN submenu as sm on (m.id=sm.parent_id)

    Home | Courses | Courses  | 
         | Course-1| Course 2 |
```

So i need Course-1 and course 2 under Courses. Please help me where i am going wrong in php code?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Are you not able to display the child items under the parent or you're not able to get the child info from the database?

Comment: Actually the final output which i am getting is last lines i.e see i am getting Course-1 under Courses and course 2 under another Courses. i want to display both Course-1 and course -2 under Courses.yes, i am not able to display child items under parent items !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {
    echo'<li><a href="'.$url.$menu[$i]['id'].'" title="'.$menu[$i]["menu_name"].'">'. $menu[$i]["menu_name"] . '</a>';
    echo'<ul>'.$menu[$i]['childs'].'</ul></li>';
}
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
    m.id, m.menu_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<li><a href=\"#\" id=\"",sm.id,"\">",sm.submenu_name,"</a></li>")) as childs
FROM menu AS m
LEFT JOIN submenu as sm on (m.id=sm.parent_id)
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is that either assign a variable to the `count($menu)` or use a foreach loop like `foreach($menu as $courseHeading)` there's a performance hit for making php evaluate the count function each time through the loop